# Ember js singleton model implementation

Tags: ember.js

When user changes URL parameters (hash) - new model is created and multiple views ( each for different model instance) are rendered at the same time. 
What is the best way to make model singleton?
Here is my code:

```
Exam.TestModel = null;


Exam.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

model: function(params) {

    // trying to remove old model
    if ( Exam.TestModel ) {
        Exam.TestModel.destroy();
        Exam.TestModel = null;
    }

    console.log(Exam.TestModel);
    Exam.TestModel = Exam.Test.create(params);

    return  Exam.TestModel;
}
});
Exam.Test = Ember.Object.extend({

init: function() {
    this._super();

    if ( this._validate() ) {
     this._loadQuestionNumbers();
    }
},
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to recreate model, when it is possible just to update properties:

```
Exam.TestModel = null;


Exam.TestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

// NOTE  autogenerated
//    setupController: function(controller, test) {
//        controller.set('content', test);
//    },
model: function(params) {

    if ( Exam.TestModel != null ) {
        Exam.TestModel.setProperties(params);
    } else {
        Exam.TestModel = Exam.Test.create(params);
    }

    return  Exam.TestModel;
}
});
```